# JavaScript: Nav Bar Drop Down inside List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please provide insight into how I can replicate the functionality shown in [this](http://www.tourneau.com/home?mkwid=s&pdv=c&pcrid=48930927341&pmt=e&pkw=tourneau&gclid=CjwKEAjwuPi3BRClk8TyyMLloxgSJAAC0XsjFLU_A4f8PPg9ovhgZDuizEoHLlbz8C9Bbs2shtMHkBoCd9Hw_wcB) example.

Specifically, the navigation bar (first tab) > Watches. The user can hover over the link and a full screen width dropdown is displayed and hides after either when a user clicks on a link or mouses out. I am creating a similar menu type drop-down and need this to function across all platforms and browsers, including ie7.

Appreciate the insight.

Comment: how about a modified bootstrap Nav? [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: "I am creating a similar menu type drop-down" you should post your code instead of the external link in the post. sooner or later this external website will be uptaded/offline and this post will become deprecated and not useful for further users.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing terribly fancy there, or that would require modern browsers, just using typical [:hover psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to show the the menus, which are initially hidden.

There is a wrapper #navigation that sets `position: relative` (this allows children to be absolutely positioned relative to it).  Then there is a `<nav>` tag inside there used to center.  Then inside of that is a `ul.level-1` with `li`'s that are `display: inline` which are the main menu items.  Then within those are the menus you are fond of, which are absolutely positioned down a bit and are 100% width.

Then the bit that displays the menu:

```
// level two menu hidden by default
div.level-2 {
  display: none;
}

// show level-2 when hovering parent menu item
ul.level-1 li:hover div.level-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the contribution.

To take this a step further, once the nav bar has been completed and inserted into a page via <div> using php, when the sub-menus drop down, how would you make the <div> expand down pushing the remaining page elements down instead of having the menu overlap?

Thank you again for the advise.